# Calling function after animation complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have 2 functions to open & close a sidebar on my page.

```
function closeSidebar(functionAfterClose) {
        var functionAfterClose = functionAfterClose || function() {};
        $("#sidebar").removeClass("open");
        $("#sidebar").animate({marginLeft: margin*-1},"fast", "swing", functionAfterClose);
        $("#dummy-column").animate({marginLeft: margin*-1},"fast", "swing");
}

function openSidebar() {
        $("#sidebar").addClass("open");
        $("#sidebar").animate({marginLeft:0},"fast", "swing");
        $("#dummy-column").animate({marginLeft:0},"fast", "swing");
}
```

I'm trying pass function to closeSidebar() to run after the close animation is complete. But it seems to run straight away rather than waiting for the sidebar animation complete.

```
closeSidebar(function() {
                alert("function called");
                $(this).addClass("current");
                openSidebar();
            });
```

What am I missing to make the function call once the animation is complete?

[The jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Mxs/6/) - Click a button on the right side, it should animate in, call the function, then animate back out again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your javascript is correct. The problem is in the CSS. You have a transition set up for the margin attribute. Erase that and your JS works fine.

Comment: I salute you for finding this. I would never have known.